# How to use boolean types in dart FFI?

Tags: dart, rust

I'm trying to use Dart FFIs with Rust. But I can't find any mention/documentation/example on how to use c compatible booleans in FFI. Even the [primitives](https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/tree/master/ffi/primitives) example from Dart official documentation didn't mention about booleans. Is it impossible to use booleans in FFI? If not, how can I approach correctly to use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out that the FFI library of Dart doesn't support the boolean types yet, (or they won't I'm not sure).
But since Rust's `bool` type is the same size as C's _Bool type, we can just use `bool` in Rust and pass `Int32` as FFI type in Dart.

**0** will become **false**, and **1** for **true**. I think it's the same result as converting an i32 to bool in Rust.

Rust implementation,

```rust
pub extern "C" fn some_function(arg: bool) {}
```

and type definition in Dart,

```dart
typedef some_function = ffi.Void Function(ffi.Int32);
```

Comment: Assuming Rust uses 8-bit bools, you should be using an `Int8` or `Uint8`. You may get a segmentation fault or weird behavior if you follow this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the accepted answer (can't comment yet), despite it works by mangling `bool` values into `ints`, the other way around caused issues in my case.

```rust
pub extern "C" fn some_function() -> bool
```

in Dart

```dart
typedef some_function = ffi.Int32 Function();
```

To convert this to a `bool` I had to do a bitmask with `1` in order to get only the first bit and then see if it was equal to zero.

I'm not sure if I'm reading invalid memory or if it is just not cleared before.

Observed in Dart 2.10.4

### Edit

As seen in the [Dart SDK](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/2.10.4/sdk/lib/ffi/ffi.dart#L592) itself, they map boolean values to `Int8` types.

Comment: Assuming Rust uses 8-bit bools, you should be using an `Int8` or `Uint8` as you allude to in your edit. You may get a segmentation fault or weird behavior if you use larger sizes.

Comment: I did get a weird behavior with a 32bit int that forced me to use a bitmask. With 8bit ints that don't occur anymore. So either I got lucky or bounds aren't checked and this is a possible security hole.

Comment: Bounds cannot be checked easily. It's may be a vulnerability, but just as many things are in C, it's up to the programmer to not screw up.